# Integrated Tomcat with ActiveMQ and Spring's DefaultMessageListenerContainer - redeliver JMS msg again

Tags: tomcat, activemq-classic, spring-integration, spring-jms

I have the following setup:
Tomcat with embedded ActiveMQ

I use Spring integrations's `JmsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` to create adapter which consumes messages from ActiveMQ queue as follows:

```
 Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(jmsConnectionFactory, TransactedMessageListenerContainer.class)
      .destination(destination)
      .errorChannel(errorChannel)
     .get();
```

where TransactedMessageListenerContainer is

```
public class TransactedMessageListenerContainer extends DefaultMessageListenerContainer {

     public TransactedMessageListenerContainer() {
         this.setSessionTransacted(true);
     } 
}
```

If exception occurs, ActiveMQ broker doesn't redeliver message accordingly.

When I use `org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService` for simple integration tests, JMS messages are redelivered, i.e. I can achieve retry mechanism

How can I achieve the same for the Tomcat with ActiveMQ?

I found here: http://activemq.apache.org/tomcat.html, that manually integrating ActiveMQ with Tomcat does allow for Topic, Queue, and ConnectionFactory injection but **does not support transactional sending and delivery**, but I am not sure whether there is some workaround or not

Thanks for help!

**UPDATE:**
I also rethrow exception in error handler as follows:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow errorHandlingFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(IntegrationContextUtils.ERROR_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME)
             .handle(this::errorMessageHandler)
             .get();
}

public void errorMessageHandler(Message<?> message) {
    log.warn("handling error message");
    log.warn("headers: " + message.getHeaders().toString());
    log.warn("payload: " + message.getPayload().toString());
    MessagingException exception = (MessagingException) message.getPayload();
    log.warn("original payload: " + exception.getFailedMessage().getPayload());
    throw exception; // make JMS broker redeliver
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to have rallback and redelivery, your error flow must rethrow an exception and not swallow like it is with default `errorChannel`. You can find similar questions and answers for them here around.

**UPDATE**

Well, not sure where is your problem I have a test-case similar to yours:

```
    @Autowired
    private MessageChannel errorChannel;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow jmsMessageDrivenFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(this.jmsConnectionFactory)
                        .configureListenerContainer(c -> c.sessionTransacted(true))
                        .errorChannel(this.errorChannel)
                        .destination("jmsMessageDriver"))
                .<String, String>transform(p -> {
                    throw new RuntimeException("intentional");
                })
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow errorHandlingFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(IntegrationContextUtils.ERROR_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME)
                .handle(m -> {
                    MessagingException exception = (MessagingException) m.getPayload();
                    Message<?> failedMessage = exception.getFailedMessage();
                    throw exception;
                })
                .get();
    }
```

and on the redelivery I see these headers in the `failedMessage`:

```
"jms_redelivered" -> "true"
"JMSXDeliveryCount" -> "2"
```

And yes, we definitely use embedded ActiveMQ in our tests.
The JMS `ConnectionFactory` is supplied for Spring Boot `ActiveMQAutoConfiguration`, by the way.

Comment: Yes, I have it like that (I updated the description). I'm not sure why it doesn't work when ActiveMQ is embedded within Tomcat

Comment: Hi Artem, thanks for your example! It opened up my eyes :) Especially, headers of the failed message. Redelivery was working for me right from the beginning, I was just getting lost in logs and couldn't make linkages between messages and flows where they are redelivered to. The only thing which is missing now is JMSXDeliveryCount msg property which is not included in the redelivered message